# View Filtering in Xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I've been trying to filter the view by second sorted column but so far it doesn't work.
(my underlying view is sorted by first column categorized and sorted by ascending, and the second column is sorted by ascending order as well) 
How can i get through this thing? and I don't want to create one more view for this filtering

Answer (score 5):

To filter by multiple keys you need to use a Java Vector with the keys you want to filter by. Here's an example of applying a filter to a sessionScope variable that you then use for the keys property of the view:

```
var vArray = new java.util.Vector();
vArray.addElement("key1");
vArray.addElement("key2");
sessionScope.put('viewFilter', vArray);
```

Comment: Hi there, thank your for the advice and what abt the key1 and key2 in the underlying view, both columns supposed to be sorted? I've tried this before but it only worked for one column (it is first sorted column) any other idea to propose???

Answer (score 0):

For search function, We have two different ways are there. One is normal search just like OS level.And another is Full index search.

Please follow the below link, U will get better idea,

```
[Search Query][1]


  [1]: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesViewControlAddFullTextSearch.htm
```